# Second Login after first logout does not work

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage, auth-guard

I've have written an API which returns a token and an userid if the login credentials are correct.
Those do I save into the local storage, like this:
[image: localstorage]
If the Users Token isn't valid anymore I clear the local storage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

The Login Code is this:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/login?username='+username+'&password='+password, JSON.stringify(params)).subscribe(res => {
if(res.token != null)
  {
    this.snackBar.open('Successfully Logged in..', 'x', {
      duration: 2000,
    });
    localStorage.setItem('auth-token', res.token)
    localStorage.setItem('userid', res.userid)
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
  }
  else{
    this.snackBar.open('User not found or wrong password..', 'x', {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }
})
```

The second time I try to login the local storage saves nothing.
I appreciate any idea :)

Comment: Try first with hardcoded value then console the value of `token` you will get the know the problem

Comment: Unrelated, but... you get back a structured object, allowing to access the token directly as a property of the object, and instead of doing that, you serialize the object as JSON, and then split the string to extract the token. Is this masochism?

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for pointing it out :) corrected it to: localStorage.setItem('auth-token', res.token)
        localStorage.setItem('userid', res.userid)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Ok sorry my fault - found the error now and corrected it. It was that I set the token when the auth-guard initializes the first time and not every time i call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Idia
you can return json data after login:

```js
/* return backend DATA JSON*/
{
  "isLogin":true,
  "remember_token":'Token'
}

//Angular front-end
isCheckLogin:boolean=false
dataUser:any={}
dataInfo:any={}

//FUNCTION LOGIN
login=()=>{
      this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/login?username='+username+'&password='+password, JSON.stringify(params)).subscribe(res => {
          this.dataUser = res;
          if(this.dataUser.islogin){
            this.isCheckLogin=true;
            localStorage.setItem('auth-token', this.dataUser.remember_token);
          }
      })
}

//FUNCTION CHECKLOGIN
check_login = ()=>{
  let data = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
  if(data.length>0){
    
    this.http.get("http://http://localhost:5000/v1/user?token="+data).subscribe(item=>{
        this.dataInfo = item;
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
    });
  
  }
}
```